# Using NEON instructions to speed up cascaded biquads - how it works?

Tags: c, optimization, signal-processing, simd, neon

I am trying to understand how the cascaded biquad filtering is optimized for Arm processors in CMSIS using Neon extensions.
The code is ifdefed under `#if defined(ARM_MATH_NEON)` [here](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/blob/develop/CMSIS/DSP/Source/FilteringFunctions/arm_biquad_cascade_df2T_f32.c), and documentation is [here](https://arm-software.github.io/CMSIS_5/DSP/html/group__BiquadCascadeDF2T.html).

The [NEON intrinsics](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/simd-isas/neon/intrinsics) are used when there are more than 4 biquads cascaded. I am puzzled how could any kind of parallel instruction execution be done if output from one biduaq is fed as input to the next one? Could anyone explain what is done in parallel in that peace of code?

Comment: SO questions need to be self-contained / resistant to link-rot; as well as linking to the source, also quote the part you're asking about.

Comment: I would suggest using your compiler's vector extensions. This will use neon automatically and easily be ported to other architectures if/when necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A biquad cascade can be parallelized by offsetting them in time.

If you compute 4 biquads at a time, the last cascade biquad doesn’t operate on the results from the previous biquad in the same batch of 4, but on results saved from the previous batch of 4.  That removes the dependencies within each batch. Thus it takes 4 steps of latency to propagate data diagonally from the first to the last biquad, but thruput finishes 4 biquads per time step, or 4x higher thruput than computing biquads one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s the formula from the documentation:

```
y[ n ] = b0 * x[ n ] + d1;
d1 = b1 * x[ n ] + a1 * y[ n ] + d2;
d2 = b2 * x[ n ] + a2 * y[ n ];
```

Let’s get rid of the mutable state by renaming variables, for 2 iterations of the loop:

```
// Iteration 1
y[ n ] = b0 * x[ n ] + d1_0;
const float d1_1 = b1 * x[ n ] + a1 * y[ n ] + d2_0;
const float d2_1 = b2 * x[ n ] + a2 * y[ n ];

// Iteration 2
y[ n + 1 ] = b0 * x[ n + 1 ] + d1_1;
const float d1_2 = b1 * x[ n + 1 ] + a1 * y[ n + 1 ] + d2_1;
const float d2_2 = b2 * x[ n + 1 ] + a2 * y[ n + 1 ];
```

When it’s written that way, it’s obvious you can substitute variables, and compute 2 iterations in parallel, here’s how:

```
// Rewriting iterations to only use data available before the #1
y[ n ] = b0 * x[ n ] + d1_0;
y[ n + 1 ] = b0 * x[ n + 1 ] + b1 * x[ n ] + a1 * b0 * x[ n ] + d1_0 + d2_0;
const float d1_2 = b1 * x[ n + 1 ] + a1 * y[ n + 1 ] + b2 * x[ n ] + a2 * y[ n ];
const float d2_2 = b2 * x[ n + 1 ] + a2 * y[ n + 1 ];
```

Pretty sure I have screwed up the algebra above, but I hope you got the idea. The approach removes data dependency at the cost of more computations.

That particular implementation does that that for 4 iterations instead of 2, by shifting vectors and doing lots of extra computations. Here’s the main NEON loop with HLSL-style comments about what is happening with the lanes of the YnV SIMD vector.

```
float32x4_t YnV = s;
// YnV.w += t1.w * dV.val[ 0 ].x;
s = vextq_f32( zeroV, dV.val[ 0 ], 3 );
YnV = vmlaq_f32( YnV, t1, s );

// YnV.zw += t2.zw * dV.val[ 0 ].xy;
s = vextq_f32( zeroV, dV.val[ 0 ], 2 );
YnV = vmlaq_f32( YnV, t2, s );

// YnV.yzw += t3.yzw * dV.val[ 0 ].xyz
s = vextq_f32( zeroV, dV.val[ 0 ], 1 );
YnV = vmlaq_f32( YnV, t3, s );

// And finally the all-lanes version without shifts:
// YnV.xyzw += t4.xyzw * XnV.xyzw
YnV = vmlaq_f32( YnV, t4, XnV );
```

Comment: OK, I get the idea, brute force algebra. However... you wrote with single biquad in mind (did you?), and the code I mentioned doesn't use any NEON unless there are 4 biquads cascaded. What do you think why would that be the case? In case of only single biquad, the CMSIS library uses only loop unrolling (check the link above), nothing more, no NEON.